# Ruby: Is it possible to determine the class that my Ruby method is executing in without hardcoding the classname?

Tags: ruby

I am a Nuby to Ruby. I am looking for a way to get the containing Class object of the method of the current line of execution. Is this possible without hardcoding the classname?

```
# hardcoded example
class A
  def to_s
    "I am a " + A.to_s   # Class "A" is hardcoded here. Is there another way to reference the class A?
  end
end
```

I thought that maybe `self.class` would work, but it didn't give me what I was looking for when the class is subclassed.

```
# Following Outputs=> I am a Camel I am a Camel I am a Camel
# but I want       => I am a Camel I am a Mammal I am a Animal

class Animal
  def to_s
    "I am a " + self.class.to_s
  end
end

class Mammal < Animal
  def to_s
    "I am a " + self.class.to_s + " " + super
  end
end

class Camel < Mammal
  def to_s
    "I am a " + self.class.to_s + " " + super
  end
end

puts Camel.new()
```

So, is there a keyword, method or something that allows accessing the containing class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Class.nesting.first
```

This gives you the defining class of a method.

```
class A
  def example
    { defining_class: Class.nesting.first, self_class: self.class }
  end
end

class B < A
end

B.new.example
# => {:defining_class=>A, :self_class=>B}
```

Comment: Really nice, I didn't think about that! Note that you'll need `Class.nesting.first.name` for the syntax the OP proposed. Also, the OP wrote in a comment he didn't want Modules, so some logic might be needed. Those are minor nitpicks anyway : Congrats!

Comment: Nesting is the lexical context, so it will always be a class for a method defined on a class. (On an unrelated note, I think OP never revealed their gender so best use "they" pronoun.)

Comment: The method could also be from a prepended Module, right? I've never used `they`. I'll just use the OP username next time.

Comment: Not sure I understand, `nesting` is not affected by `prepend` etc. As far as I know it should always return the lexical scope of the method definition.

Comment: @akuhn `Class.nesting` is exactly what I was looking for.  I also see `Module.nesting` https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-c-nesting.  If you replace all occurrences of `self.class` with `Class.nesting` in my example it works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear! Those are the same method actually because `class Class < Module` class inherits from module.

Comment: @ericduminil oh I see what you mean, `super` does not skip elements in the ancestry chain. I would say that is unrelated to `Class.nesting`

Answer (score 5):

You'll need [`Class#ancestors`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) :

```
Camel.ancestors
#=> [Camel, Mammal, Animal, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

You'll get more classes than you defined, so you'll need to stop at `Object` :

```
class Animal
  def to_s
    "I am a " + self.class.ancestors.take_while{|klass| klass != Object}.join(' and a ')
  end
end

class Mammal < Animal
end

class Camel < Mammal
end

puts Animal.new
# => I am a Animal
puts Mammal.new
# => I am a Mammal and a Animal
puts Camel.new
# => I am a Camel and a Mammal and a Animal
```

`ancestors` can be Modules or Classes, so if you just want Classes, you can use :

```
def to_s
  "I am a " + self.class.ancestors.take_while{|klass| klass < Object}.join(' and a ')
end
```

---

> So, is there a keyword, method or something that allows accessing the
>   containing class?

I couldn't find one. Adding

```
puts method(__method__).owner
```

to `Animal#to_s` or `Mammal#to_s` still returns `Camel`.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It is helpful to me since I am only day 2 into Ruby. However, I think you just improved the example code that I used to demonstrate that "self.class" wasn't what I was looking for.  Also, I think your code would include Modules if any were included. e.g " I am a Camel and a SomeModule...", and that would be inaccurate because modules are a "has a"/compositional relationship, not "is a". Right?  But all that is beside the point.  The answer that I am looking for should just get me to a single Class object, and it should replace "self.class" in all of my example classes.

Comment: I understand your question now, but didn't find anything. BTW, your problem isn't `.class`, but `self`. It stays the same Camel object, even in a method defined for `Animal`.

Comment: There is, `Class.nesting.first`